# Is it possible to store an audio file for each user in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, accessibility

I was wondering if it was possible to extend the Microsoft Graph API to include an audio file for each user. The audio would indicate how to pronounce that person's name or give a quick introduction.

I'm not sure if its possible to incorporate audio as a data type in Graph or where it would ideally be located if it was possible and in such a way that it became available to consult in other Office tools like Teams, Outlook Profile along with the users selected photo.

Anyone have any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reaching out.

AFAIK, Currently, this is not supported. Being said that, consider filing [UserVoice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific ask so it could be considered for future implementations.

Thanks.